# Rotating points via functions of their spherical coordinates

Tags: geometry, rotations

Suppose you have three points of the form $\left( \rho \cos\theta_i\cos\phi, \rho\sin\theta_i\cos\phi, \rho \sin\phi\right).$ In other words, these three points are equidistant from the origin and are parallel to the $xy-$plane.

Given a unit vector $\vec{n} \neq \vec{k} = \left<0, 0, 1\right>$, I'd like to find the functions  $\Delta\theta_i = \Delta\theta_i(\theta_i, \phi, \vec{n})$ and $\Delta\phi_i = \Delta\phi_i(\theta_i, \phi, \vec{n})$ such that the points

$$\left( \rho \cos(\theta_i + \Delta\theta_i)\cos(\phi + \Delta\phi_i), \rho\sin(\theta_i+\Delta\theta_i)\cos(\phi + \Delta\phi_i), \rho \sin(\phi + \Delta\phi_i)\right)$$

exist in the plane normal to $\vec{n}$ and maintain the same relative distances (i.e., the transformation is a rotation).

What is a good way to determine these functions?

Comment: Why did you change your question ? ... roll back the edit ?

Comment: I'm not looking for a rotation matrix. I'm looking for a way to quickly determine how to shift the angles (in this unconventional coordinate system) such that the three points exist in a plane normal to a given vector. 

I just want the functions for these shifts; the problem is I worry that these functions are not well-defined and I'm hoping for some insight into their construction. I can determine the corresponding rotation matrix using the exponential map from the Lie algebra.

Answer (score 0):

First note that you have an unorthodox convention for your spherical coordinate system ... $\cos \phi \leftrightarrow \sin \phi$ is usual.

To construct the required rotation matrix it is (probably) easiest to break it into two rotation matricies; First a rotation about the $y$-axix & then a rotation about the $z$-axis. We require the vector $(0,0,1)$ to be mapped to $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$.

We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
v_1&=&\cos(\theta') \cos(\phi') \\
v_2&=&\sin(\theta') \cos(\phi') \\
v_3&=& \sin(\phi') \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Inverting these gives 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\theta' = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{v_2}{v_1}\right) \\
\phi'=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{v_3}{\sqrt{v_1^2 +v_2^2}}\right) \\
\end{eqnarray*}
A rotation about the $y$-axis through an angle $\phi'$ is given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sin(\phi') && 0 && \cos(\phi') \\
0 && 1 && 0  \\
-\cos(\phi') && 0 && \sin(\phi')
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}
And a rotation about the $z$-axis through an angle $\theta'$ is given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta') && -\sin(\theta') && 0 \\
\sin(\theta') && \cos(\theta') && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}

We just need to compose these to get 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta') && -\sin(\theta') && 0 \\
\sin(\theta') && \cos(\theta') && 0 \\
0 && 0 && 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sin(\phi') && 0 && \cos(\phi') \\
0 && 1 && 0  \\
-\cos(\phi') && 0 && \sin(\phi')
\end{bmatrix}
=
\color{red}{\begin{bmatrix}
? && ? && ? \\
? && ? && ? \\
? && ? && ?
\end{bmatrix}}.
\end{eqnarray*}